# Converting a PHP array into HTML form inputs is duplicating items

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am attempting to take an `array` of values and build a php form from those values.

The array is at the bottom to keep the question clear. The array structure is:

```
- Item
- Item
- Item with Child   
        -Item 
        -Item
        - Item with Child   
            -Item 
            -Item
```

Here is what I want to output each `item` **but** if the item has a child, just output the name of the parent and create fields for the children.

[image]

I created this:

```
 function renderTest2(array $data)
    {
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $html .= '<li>';

            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {

                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $html .= renderTest2($value);
                } else {
                    if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
                        $html .= $item['name'];
                    } else {
                        $html .= $item['name'] . "<input type=\"text\" value=\"\"> <br/>";
                    }

                }
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }
```

Which gave me this output:

[image]

But I don't understand why it is duplicating items. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the test array I used:

```
$aFullArray = array();

$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Adam", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Beth", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");


    $aChildren = array();
    $aChildren [] = array("name" => "Mike", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
    $aChildren[] = array("name" => "Nancy", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");


    $subChild = array();
    $subChild [] = array("name" => "Peter", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
    $subChild [] = array("name" => "Paul", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");

    $aChildren [] = array("name"     => "Oscar", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
                          "children" => $subChild);

    $aFullArray[] = array("name"     => "Charlie", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
                          "children" => $aChildren);

    $aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Danny", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
```

Comment: Could it be, since each output from the `foreach()` is duplicate twice, that the structure of your `foreach` reads each type in the array, so since you've got a "name", "address" and "phone" the `foreach()` grabs all three of them, and then gets told show the "name" `foreach()` value you've come accross wich equals 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function renderTest2(array $data)
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>';
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            $html .= $item['name'];
            $html .= renderTest2($item['children']);
        } else {
            $html .= $item['name'] . "<input type='text' value=''> <br/>";
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

you are looping two times which is not required and if it has  children pass children array only

**Explanation:**

1. Loop through an array and if it has `children` key do  `recursion`
2. If not found generate li element

Comment: *facepalm* It's something so simple sometimes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code i saw the following mistake:

`foreach()` do `foreach()` so a multiple `foreach()` loop would be the mistake you've made.

try this code:

by calling `foreach()` only once and using

```
if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
   $html .= $item['name'];
   $html .= renderTest2($item['children']);
}
```

together in one `foreach()` the double loop isn't needed and `recursion` is avoided

The full code then would be:

```
<?php
$aFullArray = array();


$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Adam", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Beth", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");


$aChildren = array();
$aChildren [] = array("name" => "Mike", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$aChildren[] = array("name" => "Nancy", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");


$subChild = array();
$subChild [] = array("name" => "Peter", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$subChild [] = array("name" => "Paul", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");

$aChildren [] = array("name"     => "Oscar", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
    "children" => $subChild);

$aFullArray[] = array("name"     => "Charlie", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
    "children" => $aChildren);

$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Danny", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");

function renderTest2(array $data)
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>';
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            $html .= $item['name'];
            $html .= renderTest2($item['children']);
        } else {
            $html .= $item['name'] . "<input type='text' value=''> <br/>";
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
echo renderTest2($aFullArray);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As the original code was not making use of various elements within the source arrays I simplified for testing porpoises. Hopefully the following makes sense, it seems to generate the list in the desired manner.

```
$html = $family = $children_family_1 = $children_family_2 = array();




$family[] = array("name" => "Adam");
$family[] = array("name" => "Beth");
$family[] = array("name" => "Danny");

$children_family_2[] = array("name" => "Peter");
$children_family_2[] = array("name" => "Paul");

$children_family_1[] = array("name" => "Mike");
$children_family_1[] = array("name" => "Nancy");

$children_family_1[] = array("name" => "Oscar", "children" => $children_family_2 );
$family[] = array("name" => "Charlie", "children" => $children_family_1 );



function familytree( $input=array(),&$html ){
    $html[]='<ul>';
    foreach( $input as $index => $arr ){
        if( array_key_exists( 'children', $arr ) && is_array( $arr['children'] ) ){

            $html[]="<li>Parent: {$arr['name']}</li>";
            $html[]="<li>";

            /* recurse array to repeat structure */
            familytree( $arr['children'], &$html );

            $html[]="</li>";
        } else {
            $html[]="<li><input type='text' name='name[]' value='{$arr['name']}' /></li>";
        }
    }
    $html[]='</ul>';

    return implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
}

echo familytree( $family, $html );
```

The generated html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Adam"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Beth"></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Danny"></li>
    <li>Parent: Charlie</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Mike"></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Nancy"></li>
            <li>Parent: Oscar</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Peter"></li>
                    <li><input type="text" name="name[]" value="Paul"></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```