# Concatenate strings during an array foreach, keeping up with a parent value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array of values that I am trying parse and create a string of a parent value.

My Ideal Strings would be:

```
Adam
Beth
Charlie_
    Charlie_Mike
    Charlie_Nancy
    Charlie_Oscar_
        Charlie_Oscar_Peter
        Charlie_Oscar_Paul

Danny
```

However, I am getting

```
Adam
Beth
Charlie
    Charlie_Mike_
    Charlie_Mike_Nancy_
    Charlie_Mike_Nancy_Oscar
        Charlie_Mike_Nancy_Oscar_Peter_
        Charlie_Mike_Nancy_Oscar_Peter_Paul_
CharlieDanny_
```

As you can see, the parent value isn't clearing out when a new array is found. Additionally the `Danny` array is a top level array item and shouldn't have `Charlie` attached.

What Am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$sufix = "_";
function renderNames(array $data, $name = "")
{
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>';
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            $name .= $item['name'];
            $html .= $name . "<br/>";
            $html .= renderNames($item['children'], $name . $sufix);
        } else {
            if (strlen($name) <= 0) {
                $name = $item['name'];
                $html .= $name . "<br/>";
                $name = "";
            } else {
                $name .= $item['name'] . $sufix;
                $html .= $name . "<br/>";
            }
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

I used [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814094/how-to-find-all-parent-keys-of-an-array-from-a-given-child-key) as a reference. But I am not wanting to create an array, I want to create a string from value and here I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596026/converting-a-php-array-into-html-form-inputs-is-duplicating-items/47596441#47596441) about inputs being duplicated.

Here is the Array I am using:

```
$aFullArray = array();
$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Adam", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Beth", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");

$aChildren = array();
$aChildren [] = array("name" => "Mike", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$aChildren[] = array("name" => "Nancy", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");


$subChild = array();
$subChild [] = array("name" => "Peter", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
$subChild [] = array("name" => "Paul", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");

$aChildren [] = array("name"     => "Oscar", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
                                "children" => $subChild);

$aFullArray[] = array("name"     => "Charlie", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000",
                                "children" => $aChildren);

$aFullArray[] = array("name" => "Danny", "address" => "123 main", "phone" => "000-000-0000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are changing the `name` for each children, which lead to unexpected result. Also, you could save some conditionals and write your code in a simpler manner, like this:

```
function renderNames(array $data, $name = "")
{
    $sufix = "_";
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>';
        $html .= $name . $item['name'] . "<br/>";
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            $html .= renderNames($item['children'], $name . $item['name'] . $sufix);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Here you have a [working example](https://tio.run/##vVJda4MwFH33V4QgqOBatz3adnQde1u391FKqpGEapQYoaX0t7vE@FE3tw4ZE0Q81/N1TUayspw9ZCQzTPRcxPGSc3QEc4DU03b8S/h90w4gQwmGYL4AcBmiBLoAojDkOM81eHt3DxJEmRpkJGX1t57n3dS3B38j/ogFGSsu1VeExpLI@oVadNjzhe7x@EKN@LD2GrHgOLqQYebFrjLoFWrBYc83LDAfXeiaOCriv/hBX9XVpViveYDGxXcNcOWCQe1fsduuOtsPR7PJtiKIxxT/T7p2WVfjKa8nxNj4kxYVLBA0ZUDahZivpWxuVx7ADJFALjCVlTSG0DFOVRW5vogeFLSFvkaISGIJWLMiXlgai1KOUUCAXekAlAOTCpw44NTuQ9MmihfThtcbaPOJpr5b6s3ayHc42/HpAnYMGgEde7vHxy0@0FzkttXs1XJr80v3ntFl/dqsJW/cb3PoVThdjvNQuWnX7mx8nnUb41gUnOmhb5wNHJC0H6w7C45flh8)

As a side note: Keep in mind you the `<br/>` isn't really necessary for lists

Comment: Thanks so much! You did simplify it a lot!

Answer (score -1):

```
function renderNames(array $data, $name = "")
    {
        $sufix = "_";
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            $html .= '<li>';
            if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
                $name .= $item['name'];
                $html .= $name . "<br/>\n";
                $html .= renderNames($item['children'], $name . $sufix);
            } else {
                if (strlen($name) <= 0) {
                    $name = $item['name'];
                    $html .= $name . "\n";
                    $name = "";
                } else {
                    $aux = $name . $item['name'] . $sufix;
                    $html .= $aux . "\n";   
                }
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;

    }
```